# Sign In with Apple 実装しようと思っているのですがSigning & Capabilities に Sign in with Appleが無いです

Tags: swift, ios, swift5

SignInWithAppleを実装しようとTARGET > Signing & Capabilitiesで

Sign in with Appleを検索しているのですが見当たりません、なぜでしょうか

また解決策をご教授お願い致します。

Xcodeのversion 11.7

Comment: ありがとうございます。出てこないんです、、

Comment: なるほど、、!プロビジョニングプロファイルに紐付いている Identifier の Sign in With Apple がオンになっているでしょうか？ https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list

Answer (score 3):

`+ Capability`をクリックして一覧から`Sign in with Apple`を追加してください。

[image: capability]